# How to save the state of rediobutton throughout the application in android?

Tags: android, radio-button

I have two radio groups and each group has two radiobuttons.
the default value is true (i.e. checked ) for first radiobutton in each group.
When user cliks on any radiobutton and when user comeback from other activities the selections made on these radiogroups/radiobuttons are gone...
how can I save/restore radiogroup/radiobutton selection state ?? 
here is my java code..for one radiogroup..

```
        final RadioButton radioOn = ( RadioButton )findViewById(
        R.id.rbOn );
    final RadioButton radioOff = ( RadioButton )findViewById(
        R.id.rbOff );
    radioOn.setChecked( true );
    radioOn.setOnClickListener( auto_lock_on_listener );
    radioOff.setOnClickListener( auto_lock_off_listener );
```

please help.

Comment: take some variable and store its value.

Comment: I edited example link in my answer..

Comment: Look at my edited answer, I give a piece of code..

Answer (score 2):

You need to override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and write the application state values you want to change to the Bundle parameter like this:

```
@Override

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
      // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
      // killed and restarted.
      savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);
      savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
      savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
      savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
      // etc.
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

The Bundle is essentially a way of storing a NVP ("Name-Value Pair") map, and it will get passed in to onCreate and also onRestoreInstanceState where you'd extract the values like this:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
  boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
  double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("myDouble");
  int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
}
```

You'd usually use this technique to store instance values for your application (selections, unsaved text, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Try to save your radio group state by using SharedPreferences

```
     RadioGroup rG1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        int rG1_CheckId = rG1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

SharedPreferences rG1Prefs = getSharedPreferences("rG1Prefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = rG1Prefs.edit();
                prefsEditor.putInt("rG1_CheckId", rG1_CheckId);
                prefsEditor.commit();
```

and put this lines for get back the checked radio button id.

```
SharedPreferences rG1Prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("rG1Prefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        rG1Prefs.getInt("rG1_CheckId", null);
```

and by using this id checked the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Shared Preferences**, To save your radio button's state, Or you can use **Application Variables** (Variable which is declared globally static in that activity and you can use it in any activity)

But I think Shared Preferences is good..

Look at [Android - Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Look at this example [How to save login info to Shared Preferences Android(remember details feature)](http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=sharedpreferences-android)

**EDIT:**

```
public  class Test extends Activity   {     

private SharedPreferences prefs;
private String prefName = "MyPref";
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor; 
private static final String CHECK_STATE = "checkBox_State";
private boolean check_state;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    //---getting the SharedPreferences object....
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);    
    editor = prefs.edit();

    radioOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
        public void onClick(View v)  {               
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                check_state = true;                                 
            } else {
                check_state = false;                                    
            }
        }
    });

            // storing in shared preferences...
    editor.putBoolean(CHECK_STATE, check_state );             
    editor.commit();
    }
   });
   }
```

Comment: I am extremely new to this. can you please give me a code for that ?

Comment: It takes time for me to understand all , please give me a code directly.

Comment: thank you very much sir, i will try to do it using that example.

Comment: sir i tried a lot to make it work but its not working . please give me a code dierctly for radiobutton.

Answer (score 0):

you can store into the SharedPreference

simple example

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("on_off", 0);    
boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("onoff", false);
////// to set the value use editor object from the SharedPreferences

Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("onoff", true);
editor.commit(); // to save the value into the SharedPreference
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code -

```
mFillingGroup.check(whichFilling);
    mAddMayoCheckbox.setChecked(addMayo);
    mAddTomatoCheckbox.setChecked(addTomato);

    /**
     * We also want to record the new state when the user makes changes,
     * so install simple observers that do this
     */
    mFillingGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,
                        int checkedId) {
                    // As with the checkbox listeners, rewrite the
                    // entire state file
                    Log.v(TAG, "New radio item selected: " + checkedId);
                    recordNewUIState();
                }
            });

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkListener
            = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // Whichever one is altered, we rewrite the entire UI state
            Log.v(TAG, "Checkbox toggled: " + buttonView);
            recordNewUIState();
        }
    };
    mAddMayoCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);
    mAddTomatoCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);
}

/**
 * Handy helper routine to write the UI data to a file.
 */
void writeDataToFileLocked(RandomAccessFile file,
        boolean addMayo, boolean addTomato, int whichFilling)
    throws IOException {
        file.setLength(0L);
        file.writeInt(whichFilling);
        file.writeBoolean(addMayo);
        file.writeBoolean(addTomato);
        Log.v(TAG, "NEW STATE: mayo=" + addMayo
                + " tomato=" + addTomato
                + " filling=" + whichFilling);
}
```

And, [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BackupRestore/index.html) can help you to do whatever you need.